# Check if cell if empty

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to check if the cell (A5) in sheet tstDash is empty. Currently the cell contains a formula but sometimes it the result is blank and sometimes is a number.

If it is blank, I want a message box. Otherwise perform other function.

I have this code but it is completely ignoring the line and giving me fits.

```
If chk25thPercentile.Checked = True And Globals.tsdDash.Range("A5").Value Is DBNull.Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
If chk25thPercentile.Checked And IsDBNull(Globals.tsdDash.Range("A5").Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

What language are you writing in ? VBA or VB.Net ? VBA won't accept IsDBNull. If you are in VBA you want to be testing for the blank result of the formula, which is probably just an empty string ""
I expect you need something like

```
If chk25thPercentile.Checked And Globals.tsdDash.Range("A5").Value = ""
```

That is assuming that the result of your formula is an empty string, if the cell is actually blank, ie, without a formula you might want to look at ISBLANK

Comment: I am using VB.net with Option Strict On